# Using Cocoa to build a HTTP web server

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, apache, webserver

I am in the process of building an application suite that requires a Web Server to run on OS X to receive HTTP requests from an iOS device (or any web enabled device really). Once a request is received, the server application will then query a MySQL database, format the result into XML and return the result to the iOS application. Building the iOS app and an OS X application to query MySQL is not an issue, but I have no idea how to build the Web Server part (i.e. having a Cocoa application listening for incoming requests etc). Is it a good idea to somehow use Apache as the Web Server? If so how do I do this (i.e. Apache modules, PERL bridging to Cocoa)? If not, what are the alternatives? This application (if successfully) will potentially have many users so the Web Server must be secure (hence the reason of looking into Apache).

Comment: Not tried, but it seems like a nice tutorial for what you want to do: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

Answer (score 0):

Some simple googling delivered [a tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html) and [an open source implementation](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) of a Web Server. Maybe a good idea would be to start with these resources?

Comment: Thanks Kristof, I have seen these resources in the past however was not sure if they were heavy duty enough for my needs. I will give them a go and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but nevertheless a possible answer for others: [WebAppKit](http://webappkit.org) provides an extremely easy-to-understand approach for handling HTTP requests and responses. Ideal solution for what you're describing (as far as I can tell from your description).

Comment: Are you associated with WebAppKit?

Comment: Haha, no - not associated or related. I was just happy to find a framework which was easy enough for me to understand and worked right away. I've tried some other frameworks that had a more complex offering, and had to surrender before getting any useful results.